# PHP Array only returning first character of string

Tags: php, sql, arrays, string, forms

I'm using check-boxes to alter an SQL query.

The HTML:

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="chapter" value="7"  /><label>ch. 7</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chapter" value="13"  /><label>ch. 13</label>
```

The PHP:

```
   //adjust query for chapter
   $chap = $_POST['chapter'];
   $chapter = "";
   if(!empty($chap)){
        $N = count($chap);
        if($N == 1){
         $chapter .= " AND chapter = '".$chap[0]."'";
        }else{
         $chapter .= " AND (chapter = '".$chap[0]."' OR chapter = '".$chap[1]."')";
        }
   }    

       $zquery = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE ".$zipcodes.$chapter;
```

When the check boxes are left unchecked it works fine. When the chapter 7 box is checked it works fine. The trouble is with that 13 box. When I check that, `$chap[]` only returns a value of `"1"` instead of `"13"`. For example, when I `var_dump` `$zquery` I get `string(3384) "SELECT * FROM records WHERE (party_zip='34683' OR party_zip='34682' ) AND chapter = '1'"`.

Also, `$N` is always returning `1`, even if I check both boxes. Is `$_POST['chapter']` not an array? Why is it only returning the first character in the string?

Namaste

Comment: use foreach($_POST as $value){ echo "values=".$value."</br>";} for knowing the each and every value of Post items use print_r($_POST);

Comment: Does it work when both 7 and 13 are selected?

Comment: @AnkurSaxena if you have an answer write in answer section..

Comment: @Douglas No, the var_dump I showed was after checking both boxes. The `$N = count($chap);` is retuning 1 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Dr. Molle and Douglas are correct, but I'd like to expand a little on their answers.

`$_POST` *is* an array. It can contain a variety of values, either in a `key => value` structure or in a series of values indexed numerically. Each value can be any other type of data. In this case, your variable:

`$_POST['chapter']`

is a string, most likely - PHP interprets the array index (`[0]`, etc) as a *character* index when used against a string (or against a variable that can be trivially cast to string, like an integer or float.) This is why you're getting the first letter out instead of the first value: there's only the one value to get!

Of course, you might run into situations where the value of an array is itself an array - in which case you could access the value by typing, say, `$array[0]['candles']` or something, but that's not going to happen with the `$_POST` array (which is always an array of strings.)

Comment: Thanks for actually explaining that. I was wondering why it worked in my other scripts and not this one.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your script!

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['chapter']` is not an array,  use square brackets inside the name of the inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chapter[]" value="7"  /><label>ch. 7</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chapter[]" value="13"  /><label>ch. 13</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `[0]` if you only want one value returned from your form

```
$chapter .= " AND chapter = '".$chap."'";
```

Alternatively (and likely what you want), change your inputs to arrays and it should work

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chapter[]" value="7"  /><label>ch. 7</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chapter[]" value="13"  /><label>ch. 13</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is work as array it print all value of items post through form
to know post values use

```
echo"<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
```

`$_POST` work as array it contains all values which we posted through form.

for getting each value we can also use

```
foreach ($_POST as $value ) 
{
   echo $values."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['chapter'] is not an array. $N is returning 1 beacuse $chap is not an array, if variable is not an array then count() function always returned 1.

You can use like

> ```
>  name="chapter[]"
> ```

Then $_POST['chapter'] should be an array.